# I am getting an error java.lang.ClassCastException:

Tags: java, json, selenium, selenium-webdriver

it is an hospital application and my selenium test adds a new facility.The data required for adding the facility (eg: name of the facility, address of the facility etc)is stored as JSON file, till here it is good. I have managed to add the facility, but now after adding the facility i have to verify that the added facility is correct and the names and address of the facility matches the data in the JSON file. I have written a code but it errors as

" java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to class org.json.JSONObject (org.json.simple.JSONArray and org.json.JSONObject are in unnamed module of loader 'app') "

```
My verification method is  :

     public void verifyNewFacility2() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,ParseException {
 String Name,Description;
 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
 Object obj=parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\selenium-protect\\src\\test\\resources\\scripts\\Facility\\AddNewFacilityDetailsSection.json"));

JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
Name = (String) jsonObject.get("Selenium-Facility");
Description = (String) jsonObject.get("Test Facility created by Selenium");
WebElement nameElement =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-12']//following::div[1]//following::h3"));

String message = nameElement.getText();
Assert.assertEquals(message, Name);

WebElement descriptionElement =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-12']//following::div[1]//following::p"));


String message1 = descriptionElement.getText();
Assert.assertEquals(message1, Description);

        }
```

Comment: Like the error says: you are casting something to a `JSONObject`, but it's actually a `JSONArray`. Cast it to a `JSONArray` instead.

Comment: The error is related to this line : JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

Comment: please add your json structure to the question

Comment: @sunilnair yep. So: `JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;`

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you so much atleast that error is no more now

Comment: `[
  {
    "name": "name",
    "value": "Selenium-Facility"
  },
  {
    "name": "description",
    "value": "Test Facility created by Selenium"
  }

]` @Shrey

Comment: @AndyTurner, i have changed the code as you said, it no more gives me the error, but i will need some help here as : JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
            Name = (String) jsonArray.get(Integer.parseInt("Selenium-Facility"));
            Description = (String) jsonArray.get(Integer.parseInt("Test Facility created by Selenium"))

Comment: @AndyTurner what do i use to read the Json now?? jsonarray.get ??

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
String Name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
String Description = (String) jsonObject.get("value");
....
```

This will give only the first JSONObject as we have taken `getJsonObject(0)`, you can loop through the whole JSONArray to get all the objects

Comment: Let me know if you get any problem with this